# Automatically click on postback tab

Tags: javascript, powershell, powershell-3.0

I am working on a `PowerShell` script that is opening a URL and on that URL are 8 tabs. When I open the URL, I would like to have it automatically go to the Tab on that page that I want.

```
    function getProperty ([System.__ComObject] $obj, [string] $prop)
    {
      [System.__ComObject].InvokeMember($prop,       [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::GetProperty, $null, $obj, $null)
    }

    $ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
    $ie.visible = $true
    $ie.navigate('http://url.com/number')
    $doc = $ie.Document

    $link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a") | Where-Object {$_.class -like "class_name" -and $_.href -like "javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;Identifier)"}
    $link.click()
```

Which gives this error:

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

**HTML Code**

```
     <td style="width:5px;"></td><td onmouseover="MHover" onmouseout="MUnhover" onkeyup="Mevent" id="Tab_ID"><table class="Tab_Stuff_2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="white-space:nowrap;"><a class="class_name" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;Identifier)" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Notes</a></td>
                        </tr>
```

I'm not sure once I open the link how to call the tab I need. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: It is not really clear what you're trying to do. While I am sure it is clear in your head it is just hard to understand. Could you post what your inputs and outputs are out clearly and then maybe comment out what you're trying to do with your script and what you have so far

Comment: Just edited it to hopefully gve more info into what I am trying and what is happening